# Nsdateformatter for specific language like Spanish

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

My application is in 2 language one is English and other is Spanish. Now I receive timestamp from the server and I need to show date in "MMM dd, yyyy" formate.
this is giving me "Dec 23, 2017" but when I convert it into Spanish then I need to show month name in Spanish.
Can you please suggest do I specify 12 month name in Spanish as a short form or NSDateFormatter has this type of option.

```
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[[webserviceDict valueForKey:@"CurrentWeekEarning"]objectAtIndex:i-1]valueForKey:@"date"]];
                        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
                        strTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
```

Comment: Check `dateFormatter.locale` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html

Comment: Update your question showing how you create and setup your date formatter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the locale and create a format from template (to set correct ordering):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es"];
[formatter setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyyMMMdd"];
NSString *localizedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Localized date: %@", localizedDate); // 26 dic 2017
```

No need to add commas or other separators manually. They are also dependent on language.

The same can be achieved using predefined formats:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es"];
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5.2 example, setting Spanish **"es_ES"** locale:

```
let today = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateStyle = .long

formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "es_ES")
self.dateString = formatter.string(from: today)
```

Answer (score 0):

for specific language you need set locate

NSDateFormatter *formatter       =   [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateStyle:style];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

NSDate *temp=   [formatter dateFromString:strDate];

[formatter setDateFormat:format];

[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

Comment: no need to set style if you are setting the format. manually.  Ideally, don't set a specific format but use template to create a format for the locale, otherwise the date won't be localized correctly.